# Dynamic sheet size tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two sheets in a dashboard next to each other horizontally.
I also have a boolean parameter - when false the second sheet is invisible, when true the second sheet is visible.
I want that when the second sheet is invisible, the first one will spread to the second sheet's space.

[image: Adding picture as example]
How can I do that?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Put both in a layout container. http://www.bfongdata.com/2015/03/layout-containers-in-tableau.html

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work when the containers are horizontally.